# Percentage is different when convert Total Number from 75 or 50 to 100

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, percentages

I am creating Student result sheet facing a problem when I Convert Total Marks from 75 or 50 to 100 I get difference in percentage

on left side where total is 75 or 50 its 37.55% and on right where total is 100 its 36.67%

```
+-------+-------+----------+---------+--+-------+-------------+---------+
| Total | Marks | Obtained | Percent |  | Marks |  Obtained   | Percent |
+-------+-------+----------+---------+--+-------+-------------+---------+
|       |    75 |       40 | 53.33%  |  |   100 | 53.33333333 | 53.33%  |
|       |    75 |       13 | 17.33%  |  |   100 | 17.33333333 | 17.33%  |
|       |    75 |       25 | 33.33%  |  |   100 | 33.33333333 | 33.33%  |
|       |    75 |       38 | 50.67%  |  |   100 | 50.66666667 | 50.67%  |
|       |    75 |     30.5 | 40.67%  |  |   100 | 40.66666667 | 40.67%  |
|       |    75 |       33 | 44.00%  |  |   100 |          44 | 44.00%  |
|       |    50 |     15.5 | 31.00%  |  |   100 |          31 | 31.00%  |
|       |    50 |     11.5 | 23.00%  |  |   100 |          23 | 23.00%  |
|       |       |          |         |  |       |             |         |
| Total |   550 |    206.5 | 37.55%  |  |   800 | 293.3333333 | 36.67%  |
+-------+-------+----------+---------+--+-------+-------------+---------+
```

[Percentage Difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4Oty.png)

Comment: Perhaps it would be clearer if you did an extreme case.  A person got 95 points out 100 one test and 2 out of 5 on the second so that 97/105.  But if we scale the 2 out of 5 to 40 out of 100 you get 135/200 and 135/200 is much lower than 97/105.  Basically $\frac nx + \frac my \ne \frac {n+m}{x+y} \ne \frac {an + bm}{ax + by}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not surprising.  When you scale everything up to $100$ you are weighting the two lines with $50$ marks possible more heavily than they were in the first total.  Since they were below average efforts the percentage goes down.  If the last exam had had $5,000,000$ marks available and the student had gotten $1,150,000$ that would dominate the left column and the average there would be (very close to) $23\%$.  Somebody needs to decide how the exams should be weighted.